# Issue converting a 3-dimensional DataFrame to a 3-dimensional array using PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**I first created an array:**

```
nlist= [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]],[[19,20,21],[22,23,24],[25,26,27]]]
import numpy as np
narray = np.array(nlist)
```

**Then I converted it into a dataframe using:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(narray)
```

**So I basically converted a 3-dimensional array to a 3-dimensional dataframe.
Now when I try to get it back as an array using:**

```
new_array = np.array(df)
```

**Now this returns a 2-dimensional array** *(used new_array.shape to check dimensions)* **. But I want the original 3-dimensional array. What do I do?**

Comment: Show the dataframe (atleast a few rows) and new_array. With dtypes. So both of us understand what is happening.  A normal dataframe is 2d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
new_array = np.array(df.values.tolist())



print(narray)
print(type(narray))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(narray)
print(df)
**new_array = np.array(df.values.tolist())**
print((new_array))
print(type(new_array))
```

O/P:

```
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]]

 [[10 11 12]
  [13 14 15]
  [16 17 18]]

 [[19 20 21]
  [22 23 24]
  [25 26 27]]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
              0             1             2
0     [1, 2, 3]     [4, 5, 6]     [7, 8, 9]
1  [10, 11, 12]  [13, 14, 15]  [16, 17, 18]
2  [19, 20, 21]  [22, 23, 24]  [25, 26, 27]
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]]

 [[10 11 12]
  [13 14 15]
  [16 17 18]]

 [[19 20 21]
  [22 23 24]
  [25 26 27]]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```